# Saving animations in pyzo on a mac

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I've been trying to save python matplotlib animations as a gif/video.
I didn't find any convincing solution online.

I tried installing ffmpeg (through homebrew) but I still cannot save using `anim.save("filename")`. The error given is :

```
MovieWritter ffmpeg unavailable.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib will assume the ffmpeg binary in the path specified in the `'animation.ffmpeg_path'` rc parameter. This leads to two options.

1. Modify the `'animation.ffmpeg_path'` rc parameter to point to the location of ffmpeg on disk. Note that this is the actual binary, not just the folder. Do so by either

   ```
   plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = "path/to/ffmpeg"
   ```

   or by adding the line `animation.ffmpeg_path : path/to/ffmpeg` to your [rc file](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file)
2. Make sure the path to ffmpeg is in your operating system's $PATH, i.e. that you can run `ffmpeg` from any folder of your system.

Comment: Thank you for your time ! I'm totally new to this whole aspect, so I'm not sure how to do what you described :
1. How can I make sure I'm giving the right path ?
2. When I try to run ffmpeg in terminal , I get the message :
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libx264.138.dylib
  Referenced from: /path/anaconda3/bin/ffmpeg
  Reason: image not found
Any Idea what this means ?

Comment: For 1. You need to find out where ffmpeg is installed and use that path. For 2. No idea, but seems you're not the first with that issue https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/27866